# how to separate two conditions in a figure using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data like this

```
df<-structure(list(X = c("Condition1_r1", "Condition1_r1", "Condition1_r1", 
"Condition1_r1", "Condition1_r1", "Condition1_r1", "Condition1_r2", 
"Condition1_r2", "Condition1_r2", "Condition1_r2", "Condition1_r2", 
"Condition1_r2", "Condition1_r3", "Condition1_r3", "Condition1_r3", 
"Condition1_r3", "Condition1_r3", "Condition1_r3", "Condition2_r1", 
"Condition2_r1", "Condition2_r1", "Condition2_r1", "Condition2_r1", 
"Condition2_r1", "Condition2_r2", "Condition2_r2", "Condition2_r2", 
"Condition2_r2", "Condition2_r2", "Condition2_r2", "Condition2_r3", 
"Condition2_r3", "Condition2_r3", "Condition2_r3", "Condition2_r3", 
"Condition2_r3"), group = c("Start", "X24h", "Start", "X24h", 
"Start", "X24h", "Start", "X24h", "Start", "X24h", "Start", "X24h", 
"Start", "X24h", "Start", "X24h", "Start", "X24h", "Start", "X24h", 
"Start", "X24h", "Start", "X24h", "Start", "X24h", "Start", "X24h", 
"Start", "X24h", "Start", "X24h", "Start", "X24h", "Start", "X24h"
), replicate = c("0.05", "0.05", "0.1", "0.1", "0.5", "0.5", 
"0.05", "0.05", "0.1", "0.1", "0.5", "0.5", "0.05", "0.05", "0.1", 
"0.1", "0.5", "0.5", "0.05", "0.05", "0.1", "0.1", "0.5", "0.5", 
"0.05", "0.05", "0.1", "0.1", "0.5", "0.5", "0.05", "0.05", "0.1", 
"0.1", "0.5", "0.5"), value = c(1985690L, 1806206L, 1730114L, 
1834778L, 1755666L, 1865112L, 1648182L, 1808040L, 1725849L, 1869877L, 
1668527L, 1830708L, 1753785L, 1891484L, 1789878L, 1937330L, 1695593L, 
1863313L, 1503562L, 1625457L, 1740597L, 1888427L, 1751354L, 1901987L, 
1766865L, 1941141L, 1701077L, 1886134L, 1720210L, 1901676L, 1668165L, 
1861851L, 1713350L, 1902281L, 1657771L, 1857649L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

It has two conditions (condition 1 and 2) with 3 replicates. I try to plot it with box plot but I cannot distinguish them from each other.

I plot it like this, do you have any suggestion to make speparate those conditions?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = value, fill = factor(replicate))) +
  geom_boxplot()



df2<- structure(list(X = c("test_r1", "test_r2", "test_r3", "Condition2_r1", 
"Condition2_r2", "Condition2_r3"), Start_0.05 = c(1985690L, 1648182L, 
1753785L, 1503562L, 1766865L, 1668165L), X24h_0.05 = c(1806206L, 
1808040L, 1891484L, 1625457L, 1941141L, 1861851L), Start_0.1 = c(1730114L, 
1725849L, 1789878L, 1740597L, 1701077L, 1713350L), X24h_0.1 = c(1834778L, 
1869877L, 1937330L, 1888427L, 1886134L, 1902281L), Start_0.5 = c(1755666L, 
1668527L, 1695593L, 1751354L, 1720210L, 1657771L), X24h_0.5 = c(1865112L, 
1830708L, 1863313L, 1901987L, 1901676L, 1857649L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, here is one potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)

df2<- structure(list(X = c("test_r1", "test_r2", "test_r3", "Condition2_r1", 
                           "Condition2_r2", "Condition2_r3"), Start_0.05 = c(1985690L, 1648182L, 
                                                                             1753785L, 1503562L, 1766865L, 1668165L), X24h_0.05 = c(1806206L, 
                                                                                                                                    1808040L, 1891484L, 1625457L, 1941141L, 1861851L), Start_0.1 = c(1730114L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     1725849L, 1789878L, 1740597L, 1701077L, 1713350L), X24h_0.1 = c(1834778L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     1869877L, 1937330L, 1888427L, 1886134L, 1902281L), Start_0.5 = c(1755666L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      1668527L, 1695593L, 1751354L, 1720210L, 1657771L), X24h_0.5 = c(1865112L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      1830708L, 1863313L, 1901987L, 1901676L, 1857649L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              -6L))
df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(-X,
               names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)",
               names_to = c("group", "replicate")) %>%
  mutate(condition = ifelse(str_detect(X, "Condition"),
                            "Condition",
                            "Test"),
         group = factor(str_remove(group, "^X"), levels = c("Start", "24h")),
         replicate = factor(replicate)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = interaction(condition, group, sep = "/"), y = value, fill = replicate)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Test/Start", "Test/24h"),
                                 c("Condition/Start", "Condition/24h")),
              map_signif_level = function(p) {sprintf("*p = %.2g", p)},
              test = "wilcox.test", test.args = list(exact = FALSE),
              textsize = 5, step_increase = 0.1) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: this sounds good, what if the naming was two different naming also how to get raid of X before the numbers in y axis?

Comment: "what if the naming was two different naming" <- I don't know; if you edit your example data to illustrate what you mean (and the expected outcome) I should be able to help you with it @nik

Comment: I just added a second data above in my question. would you be able to make the significant differences between each group ?

Comment: Thanks for including additional information in your question @nik; I've edited my answer with a potential solution - let me know if I've misunderstood your expected outcome

Comment: thanks I modified for my need, only issue is the I get the following error `Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_signif()`
Caused by error in `wilcox.test.default()`:
! not enough 'y' observations `  do you know why? or how to solve it

Comment: I asked another question